# Assigning variables to output parameters in a PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm starting a PostgreSQL project, after many years with Sybase and SQL Server, and am new to it's quirks, but so far have been impressed.

I've written a small function that returns OUT parameters. I pass in a clear password and the function returns the encrypted password and a salt. Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iSecGenPwdSalt(pwdin text, out salt text, out userpassword text)
AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 

    BEGIN
        -- Generate a salt...
        salt = gen_salt('bf', 10);

        -- Now generate the password hash...
        userpassword = crypt(pwdin, salt);
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION iSecGenPwdSalt(text, out text , out text ) OWNER TO postgres;
```

I'd like to call this function within a trigger and use the values to populate the password and salt columns I have, but I can't fathom the syntax. I've tried multiple variations ona theme but I'm still having problems.

`select salt, userpassword from iSecGenPwdSalt('mymagicpassword');`

Returns it's results beautifully, so I'd like to call this function and get the results into a pair of variables in a trigger so I can assign the values.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT usersalt=salt, userpwd=userpassword 
  FROM iSecGenPwdSalt(NEW.systemuserpassword);
```

The error I get is thus:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>   HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "isec_trg_systemuser" line 13 at SQL statement

So simply assigning a pair of variables to a resultset derived from OUT parameters in a trigger is causing me grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific situation I think that you could use `SELECT INTO` statement with multiple columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION userAuth_insert_f() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO NEW.usersalt, NEW.userpwd
        salt, userpassword FROM iSecGenPwdSalt(NEW.systemuserpassword);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Full example (using [`pgcrypto`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) contrib module):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userAuth; 
CREATE TABLE userAuth (
    id serial,
    systemuserpassword text,
    usersalt text,
    userpwd text
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iSecGenPwdSalt
    (pwdin text, OUT salt text, OUT userpassword text)
AS $$ BEGIN
    salt = gen_salt('bf', 10);
    userpassword = crypt(pwdin, salt);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS userAuth_insert_t ON userAuth;
CREATE TRIGGER userAuth_insert_t
    BEFORE INSERT ON userAuth
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE userAuth_insert_f();
```

Invoking:

```
=>INSERT INTO userAuth (systemuserpassword) VALUES ('mymagicpassword');
INSERT 0 1
=>SELECT usersalt, userpwd FROM userauth;
           usersalt            |                           userpwd                
-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 $2a$10$7FqU5a/DrM.CWGlQPlGz6e | $2a$10$7FqU5a/DrM.CWGlQPlGz6eLjuN3UTwh/hlgxTnogS..
(1 row)
```

Comment: I think you're right - I have to change the way I approach the problem. Perhaps I was thinking in the Sybase/SQL Server mentality of selecting into variables. The SELECT INTO NEW.columnname seems like a good workaround and perhaps a better approach than that which I set out to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to the question you're asking, but I had to do a similar thing recently, and I did it with a view and rules instead of triggers. I hope this is helpful despite not really being an answer to the question your asked directly.

Here is my user table and view:

```
CREATE TABLE users_t (
  username VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
  email    VARCHAR UNIQUE,
  password CHAR(60),
  salt     CHAR(29)
);

CREATE VIEW users AS SELECT username, email, '********'::varchar AS password FROM users_t;
```

The insert rule takes care of generating the salt value:

```
CREATE RULE users_insert_rule AS ON INSERT TO users DO INSTEAD
INSERT INTO users_t (username, email, password, salt) 
  SELECT new.username, new.email, crypt(new.password, salt.salt), salt.salt 
  FROM (SELECT gen_salt('bf') as salt) salt
RETURNING username, email, '********'::varchar;
```

For completeness I'm including the update and delete rules, even though they aren't especially relevant:

```
CREATE RULE users_update_rule AS ON UPDATE TO users DO INSTEAD
  UPDATE users_t 
  SET 
    username = new.username, 
    email = new.email, 
    password = crypt(new.password, salt)
RETURNING username, email, '********'::varchar;

CREATE RULE users_delete_rule AS ON DELETE TO users DO INSTEAD
  DELETE FROM users_t WHERE username = old.username
RETURNING username, email, '********'::varchar;
```

Then I wrote an authentication function which takes care of using the salt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION authenticate(varchar, varchar) RETURNS setof users AS $$
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username =
  (SELECT username FROM users_t 
   WHERE username = $1 AND crypt($2, salt) = password)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

So you can "log in" by querying `SELECT * FROM authenticate('username', 'password');` and your users are created by inserting into the `users` view. You can set the permissions such that you have an unprivileged role that can see the users view but not the underlying users_t table. This way you have an easy to interface with users table with salted passwords without having to deal with the salt in the application.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think the solutions presented here from both you and Grzegorz Szpetkowski are eminently usable and both point towards the SELECT INTO NEW.columnname approach, rather than intermediate variables.